# Vertical space between chapter heading and table

Tags: tables, spacing, vertical-alignment

In my appendix I have only chapters followed by one or more tables each. These tables are captioned. But I'd like the tables to begin after the usual vertical space which is put if you simply write some text following a chapter.

Here is a very short MWE to illustrate this. As you can see, the vertical space between the heading and the chapter is much bigger than the one between the heading and some text.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, smallheadings,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{-1\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption[title table 1]{description table 1}
\fbox{content}
\end{table}
\chapter{Chapter}
aaa
\end{document}
```

**edit**: I realized that `\captionsetup{aboveskip=0pt}` reduces the space. So the space seems to come from the caption package? What is the right value to use (some tests have shown that it's not zero but has to be a little negative)? Also how can I set this locally for the whole appendix but not for the content before?

Original question: How can the vertical space between the heading and the table be set to the same value as between the heading and the text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove that gap either issuing

```
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-12.75pt}
```

or (after loading `caption`)

```
\captionsetup[table]{aboveskip=-12.75pt}
```

Note that both the above commands affect only the code that follows them, so you can simply put them after you start with the appendices.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, smallheadings,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{-1\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-12.75pt}
\chapter{Chapter}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption[title table 1]{description table 1}
\fbox{content}
\end{table}
\chapter{Chapter}
aaa
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I see two possible solutions: simply typesetting \raggedbottom locally — or considering that your tables don't have to float, after all: they *have* to be after the chapter heading. So you could try this, using the subcaption package:

```
\chapter{Chapter}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\captionsetup{type=table}
\begin{subtable}\caption{description table1}\label{tabA1}Table A.1\end{subtable}
\begin{subtable}\caption{description table2}\label{tabA2}Table A.2\end{subtable}
\begin{subtable}\caption{description table3}\label{tabA3}Table A.3\end{subtable}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: thanks for your entry, but unfortunately it didn't work for me. `raggedbottom` does not seem to change the distance in `scrreprt`? I have also just tried the second solution but it throws: Missing number, treated as zero \begin{subtable}\caption and Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) \begin{subtable}\caption

Comment: Could you provide a working solution? I upvoted you of course but right now I am still looking for a solution.